# Selecting an option of select tag based on text inside

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown like this :

```
<select id="mySelect" size="4">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

**I have another var fruit = "some_fruit" and I want to select the item in the options based on the value of the variable some_fruit**.

The selection has to be done using javascript DOM.

**What I have tried so far :**

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").options.namedItem("orange").text;
```

But this selects the option using the id.

**One possible solution :**

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var txt = "";
var some_fruit = "some_fruit";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    txt = x.options[i].text;

    if (txt == some_fruit) {

        // Hooray! We are done.
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it without looping the select tag options ?

Comment: Just `document.getElementById("mySelect").value = VARIABLE`

Comment: Oh..its that simple...I will try out....thanks :D :)

Comment: @Rayon .value selects it based on the value inside the tag. Your solution would work on something like `<option value="Orange">Orange</option>`

Comment: Using the value attribute in the option element is the best way to do it, are you sure you can't have those values set?
There is no selector targeting text directly from what i understood of the specification

Comment: With `jQuery`, you can use `:contains` selector but `jQ` is not tagged. And not that you may not see a loop using `jQuery` but internally, it does loop elements based on selector.. Using `querySelector`, `attribute selector` could be used if `value` attribute exists in `DOM`

Comment: A loop is the "normal" way. You can make the loop code a little shorter by eliminating the `txt` variable and just testing `if(x.options[i].text===some_fruit)`, though you may want to add a `break` inside the if.